# can we use flurry analytics for web application ? if yes, how?

Tags: analytics, flurry

Is there any way I can use flurry analytics for my website for event tracking. just same as we use Google event tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified on flurry website and blogs for this question saying flurry analytics can only be used for the mobile platform not for web application platforms.